# Rails, Sidekiq & Unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unicorn, sidekiq

I am having some problems getting Sidekiq to run on my VPS. Everything works fine locally but once I deploy I get the following error in my unicorn log:

```
E, [2012-09-18T21:41:19.670672 #1308] ERROR -- : uninitialized constant MailchimpWorker::Sidekiq (NameError)
/home/deployer/production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/ext/module.rb:36:in `const_missing'
/home/deployer/production/releases/20120919013128/app/workers/mailchimp_worker.rb:3:in `<class:MailchimpWorker>'
/home/deployer/production/releases/20120919013128/app/workers/mailchimp_worker.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/deployer/production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
/home/deployer/production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
/home/deployer/production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!'
/home/deployer/production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
/home/deployer/production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
/home/deployer/production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/home/deployer/production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/home/deployer/production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/home/deployer/production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/deployer/production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/home/deployer/production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/home/deployer/production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
/home/deployer/production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/home/deployer/production/releases/20120919013128/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
config.ru:4:in `require'
config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
/home/deployer/production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
/home/deployer/production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
config.ru:1:in `new'
config.ru:1:in `<main>'
```

Here is the contents of my worker file:

```
class MailchimpWorker

  include Sidekiq::Worker

  LIST_ID = '844161948b'

  def perform(email)
    Gibbon.listSubscribe id: LIST_ID, email_address: email
  end

end
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try requiring 'sidekiq' or 'sidekiq/worker' in the worker file

Comment: I tried each of those but get `no such file to load`

Comment: Are you using bundler to manage dependecies? If so, is 'gem "sidekiq"" in your Gemfile?

Comment: Yes I am using Bundler and sidekiq is in my Gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like `gem 'sidekiq'` is missing from your Gemfile.

Comment: I have sidekiq in my Gemfile. Also if I do `bundle exec irb` and then `require "sidekiq"` it loads fine. Also it works correctly when I run the application locally.

Comment: Does it appear when you run `$ bundle show`? Is it in the right group? (i.e. not development/test) Did you hack anything dependency-related in the Rails boot process (`config/{application,boot,environment}.rb`)?

Answer (score 0):

If it works on dev but not production, it sounds like bundler isn't loading the gem in the production environment. Which depends on what group the gem is listed in your Gemfile and also how you deploy (how do you have bundler install your gems on production?).

So, can you post your Gemfile, and also the relevant bits in your deployment scripts?

Also double check that the sidekiq procs are being started using bundle exec.

Answer (score 0):

are you running unicorn inside of bundler?

```
bundle exec unicorn
```